# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, sqlite

This Python class is supposed to query an SQLite database:

```py
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('devel.db')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.connection.commit()
    
    def query(self, query, params=()):
        if params == ():
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(query, params)
        self.connection.commit()
        return True
    
    def select(self, query, params=()):
        if params == ():
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(query, params)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

id = 1
Database.select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", (id,))
```

It gives :

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

I also tried `self.connection.cursor()` instead of `self.cursor`.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

To call the `query` method, you need to first create an instance of the `Database` class.

Basically, by calling the `query` method without an object, you are passing the query string as the `self` parameter, so it tries to access the `cursor()` method in a string and not the class itself.

So instead of executing this code:

```py
Database.select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", (id,))
```

You need to do something like this:

```py
db = Database()

db.select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", (id,))
```